# blender soft body not updating after obstacle moved

Tags: soft-body

I have a soft body plane, and want to delay it's movement. To do this, I added a plane, that stops the soft body. the problem is, when the obstacle moves, the soft body stays in place. does anyone know how to get it to move when the obstacle is gone?

Comment: maybe go to the cache settings of the soft body and see if there is a bake and delete it and if there isn't maybe baking it will help, otherwise have you set the plane to be a obstacle in the physics tab?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your plane (that stops the soft body) has collision turn on. Then also make it a rigid body (type "passive") and animated:

[image: Animated, collision plane for physics]

Now you can animate the plane's movement the way you want. The soft body ball (in my case) will interact with it.

[image]